# Optimize my code from @Provides to bind in my guice package

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

In my code, in module package,  I am using binding using @Provides in my google guice package for binding. This is my working code.

But I want to optimize my code using bind instead of @provides. I tried various ways, but getting different exceptions. Can someone please suggest me the solution? Thanks

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(MY_CONSTANT)
    public MyObjectRepository myObjectRepository(final DatabaseRepository<ObjectDAO> objectDAODatabaseRepository,
                                                 final DefaultMyObjectDAOTranslator defaultMyObjectDAOTranslator) {
        return new DynamoDBMyRepository(myDAODatabaseRepository, defaultMyDAOTranslator);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public DatabaseRepository<MyObjectDAO> myObjectDAODatabaseRepository(final DAOWriter<MyObjectDAO> daoWriter,
                                                                     final DAORetriever<MyObjectDAO> daoRetriever) {
        return new DynamoDBRepository<>(daoWriter, daoRetriever);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public DAOWriter daoWriter(final IDynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper) {
        return new DAOWriter(dynamoDBMapper);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public DAORetriever<MyObjectDAO> myObjectDAORetriever(final IDynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper) {
        return new DAORetriever<>(dynamoDBMapper, MyObjectDAO.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following should be working:

```
bind(MyObjectRepository.class)
  .annotatedWith(Names.named(MY_CONSTANT))
  .to(DynamoDBMyRepository.class)
  .in(Singleton.class);

bind(new TypeLiteral<DatabaseRepository<MyObjectDAO>>(){})
  .to(DynamoDBRepository.class)
  .in(Singleton.class);

bind(new TypeLiteral<DAOWriter<MyObjectDAO>>(){})
  .to(DAOWriter.class)
  .in(Singleton.class);

bind(new TypeLiteral<DAORetriever<MyObjectDAO>>(){})
  .to(DAORetriever.class)
  .in(Singleton.class);
```

Because of the large amount of classes/files, I've not tested this. Also, at some point you write that `DAOWriter` is generic and at another point, you skip that generic specification, so for the sake of consistency, I kept that generic part.